# Getting 500 (Internal Server Error) on wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help, im trying to do a `wp_insert_post` with a htmlform (php and wordpress). I keep getting a 500 server error and i dont understand why, can you please help me? (the prints and echoes is for testing some stuff).

```js
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ){
        print((isset ($_POST['title1'])));
        // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
        if (isset ($_POST['title1'])) {
            $title =  $_POST['title1'];
        } else {
            echo 'fyll i';
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
            $description = $_POST['description'];
        } else {
            echo 'fyll i';
        }
         if (isset ($_POST['message'])) {
            $message = $_POST['message'];
        } else {
            echo 'fyll i';
        }
        $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        echo('ny entry');
    
        print_r($new_post);
    
        $new_post = array(
           'post_title'    => $title,
           'post_content' => $message,
           'post_name'  => $description,
           'post_status'   => 'publish',
           'post_type' => 'omdmen'
            
        );
    
        print_r($new_post);
        $new_post = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    
    }    
    
    echo('finished');

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="postbox">
    <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="votepost.php">
        <p><label for="title">Ide</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title1" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="description">Hantverk</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="description" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="description" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="message">Budskap</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="message" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="message" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

$title,
           'post_content' => $message,
            'post_name'  => $description,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'omdmen'

        );

    print_r($new_post);
        $new_post = wp_insert_post($new_post); 

    }    

    echo('finished');

?>

Comment: when using wordpress code outside the context of wordpress you need to load the wordpress engine first. you have to do `require_once('path/to/wp/root/wp-load.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Are the $title, $description elsewhere in the code initiated? When the code reached the  '$new_post = array' line maybe the variables doesn't exists.

What happens if you set the variables on the top of your code like this:

```
$title = 'This is my title';
$message = 'This is my message';
$description = 'This is my description';
```

Does it get saved?